# How I can convert timestamp between Algolia & Firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

I got this error when I try to add Object:

Unhandled Exception: `{error: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Timestamp'}`

[image]

Comment: Have you defined the `toJson` method in other classes, which is what `json.encode` is looking for: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html

Comment: And it will be helpful if you post part of code which is generating this error